# Live Streaming over rtmps using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, ssl, rtmp

Facebook has deprecated rtmp for Live API. My question now is how to use ffmpeg to stream live over rmtps? Here is my last command.

```
ffmpeg -re -i 'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4' -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 720x480 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv rtmp://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/...
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it looks like `ffmpeg` currently has a [bug on file](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6471) that breaks RTMPS.

Solutions I have seen suggested elsewhere:

- Use another tool that supports RTMPS, such as OBS
- Send a `ffmpeg` RTMP stream through `stunnel`, forwarding the RTMP data over TLS to the target RTMPS server

Comment: Wow, nice job finding that bug in ffmpeg's Trac, @Lemon Cat.  It's now a 5 year old open bug from June 19, 2017 (!!!).  Yikes.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/... instead of rtmp://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/...

```
ffmpeg -re -i 'https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/480/big_buck_bunny_480p_30mb.mp4' -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 720x480 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/...
```

Comment: I run FFmpeg 3 on my server and it doesn't support rtmps

Comment: what about zeranoe builds ? 
https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/